# Easy way to execute remote admin commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm finishing up my survival games map, adding final touches and such, but... I need an easy way to execute remote admin commands, like setting my own gamemode to creative, starting the game, or resetting the game. Right now, I am using a tellraw command on a clock, so I can easily and quickly click on the options in the chat.

Here is my current setup:
[image]

Often times, though, it spams the chat and gets in the way... Is there any way to play *in* the game, *and* be able to control the game remotely without using the current setup? Or maybe have the tellraw occupy one line, always on the bottom of the chat?

Comment: You could try something that checks what slot your cursor is on, then if you left click on something, it puts something in chat depending on the slot relating to the command?

Comment: Since I would like to play also, would it work despite any item in my inventory?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a book that in which you can execute commands. I don't fully understand the detailed method of creating books with commands but there's a very simple tool on [minecraftjson.com](http://minecraftjson.com/).

For example, here's a simple book to set your gamemode to creative or survival:

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Hello, \"},{\"selector\":\"@p\"},{\"text\":\"!\n\n\"},{\"text\":\"Gamemode:\n - \"},{\"text\":\"Creative\n\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"underlined\":\"true\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/gamemode 1 @p\"}},{\"text\":\" - \",\"color\":\"none\",\"underlined\":\"false\"},{\"text\":\"Survival\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"underlined\":\"true\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/gamemode 0 @p\"}}]"],title:Book,author:TellrawGenerator}
```

Alternatively you can have triggers you can type to execute a series of commands or just a trigger to bring up the menu you are using right now.

Comment: @TrivisionZero You might have missed the link, which is more useful than any amount of code, seeing that in any case you get a single, very long command (the example I added is 520 characters long, and doesn't even do much)